# Should a cook be concerned about the type of symmetrical edge-grind from the manufacturer on a chef's knife?

Tags: equipment, knives, sharpening

*Asymmetrical edges are out of scope of my question because I feel like they're too different from symmetrical edges as it relates to the question.*

If the stock edge-grind on a chef's knife is any rounded variation, is that something that should be avoided due to a less well-defined guiding angle for future sharpening?

Does it have any material effect on knife performance if the quality of the edge is comparable in polish, angle, etc?

[This has some examples of edge grinds](http://www.imadeaknife.com/articles/the-only-article-about-knife-grinds-youll-ever-need/)

[image: Edge grinds]

In the above picture, all but the chisel type is symmetrical.

Hollow and convex are examples of the types I would be concerned about during the first non-factory sharpening.

Comment: Hmmm ... can you give some examples/links?  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "rounded variation".

Comment: I'd say so; you can't really sharpen hollow-ground knives using a knife block at home.  However, I don't have definitive enough information to offer this as an answer.

Comment: This video https://youtu.be/7nTBEbMQBGQ?t=1076 up to about 18:20 he mentions that hollow-ground edges "melts away" when they touch the whetstone.